# Expiration date on javascript cookie is not working -updated

Tags: javascript

UPDATE - made with suggestions from below:
I have the following script that pops up a window, after 3 visits, and to only 20% of visitors.  The expiration date is set and shows in Developer tools for expiring in 180 days, but it's still popping up.  What am I doing wrong?  Any help is appreciated, I do not know javascript at all very well.  This has to be done all in plain javascript - no jQuery

```
//setting the expiration date to 6 months from now//
expDate = new Date;
// in the following line, 180 means 180 days.// 
expDate.setTime(expDate.getTime() + 180 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
expDate.toGMTString();
//making the cookie//
function setCookie(name, value, expires, path, domain, secure) {
  document.cookie = name + "=" + escape(value) +
    ((expires) ? "; expires=" + expires.toGMTString() : "") +
    ((path) ? "; path=/wmb" + path : "") +
    ((domain) ? "; domain=www.example.com" + domain : "") +
    ((secure) ? "; secure" : "");
}

function getCookie(name) {
  var dc = document.cookie;
  var prefix = name + "=";
  var begin = dc.indexOf("; " + prefix);
  if (begin == -1) {
    begin = dc.indexOf(prefix);
    if (begin != 0) return null;
  } else {
    begin += 1;
  }
  var end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", begin);
  if (end == -1) {
    end = dc.length;
  }
  return unescape(dc.substring(begin + prefix.length, end));
}
//cookie name is called CustomSurvey//
visits = getCookie('CustomSurvey');
if (!visits) {
  visits = 1
};
if (visits < 4)
  //Math.random is set so that 20% of those visits actually get the popup//
  if ((Math.random() * (100 - 1) + 1) < 20) {
    //get location of where this popup came from; also contains variable from SM that will trickle down into reporting to tell where it came from//
    var currentLocation = window.location;
    window.open("https:mysurvey.com" + "_blank", "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=500,left=500,width=400,height=400");
  }
if (visits < 3) {
  ++visits;
  cookieData = visits;
  setCookie('CustomSurvey', cookieData, expDate)
}
```

I changed to what you suggested (except the url - that part is just made up (the real one pops up).  I did everything suggested except when I changed the visits > 3 , now nothing pops up (after clearing cache and clicking about 50 times.

This is what I have now:

```
//setting the expiration date to 6 months from now//
expDate = new Date;
// in the following line, 180 means 180 days.// 
expDate.setDate(expDate.getDate() + 180)
//making the cookie//
function setCookie(name, value, expires, path, domain, secure){
document.cookie= name + "=" + escape(value) +
((expires) ? "; expires=" + expires.toGMTString() : "") +
((path) ? "; path=/wmb" + path : "") +
((domain) ? "; domain=ptoweb.uspto.gov" + domain : "") +
((secure) ? "; secure" : "");
}

function getCookie(name) {
    var dc = document.cookie;
    var prefix = name + "=";
    var begin = dc.indexOf("; " + prefix);
    if (begin == -1) {
        begin = dc.indexOf(prefix);
        if (begin != 0) return null;
    } else {
        begin += 1;
    }
    var end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", begin);
    if (end == -1) {
        end = dc.length;
    }
    return unescape(dc.substring(begin + prefix.length, end));
}
//cookie name is called CustomSurvey//
visits = getCookie('CustomSurvey');
if (!visits) {
    visits = 1
};
if (visits > 3)
//Math.random is set so that 20% of those visits actually get the popup//
    if ((Math.random() * (100 - 1) + 1) < 20) {
      //get location of where this popup came from; also contains variable from SM that will trickle down into reporting to tell where it came from//
       var currentLocation = window.location;
        window.open("https://www.surveymonkey" + "?" + currentLocation, "_blank", "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=500,left=500,width=400,height=400");
    }
if (visits < 3) {
    ++visits;
    cookieData = visits;
    setCookie('CustomSurvey', cookieData, expDate)
}
```

Comment: When the cookie expires, it sets it again.

Comment: The `window.open()` call looks wrong. The URL is missing `//` before the domain, and `"_blank"` should be a separate argument, not concatenated to the URL.

Comment: To add 180 days to a date, you can use `expDate.setDate(expDate.getDate() + 180)`, you don't need all that multiplication.

Comment: `expDate.toGMTString();` doesn't do anything.

Comment: The question says "pops up a window, after 3 visits". Your code pops up the window on the first 3 visits, not after 3 visits. The popup should be in `if (visits > 3)`, not `if (visits < 4)`.

Comment: I updated it like you suggested - but now the pop up wont show up at all....

Comment: Try changing 20% to something higher during testing.

Comment: I did that but the value on the cookie is no not reaching over 2 - so it won't meet the minimum 3 visits so the pop-up wont work

Comment: You only increment it when it's less than 3. Why do you do that?

Comment: Get rid of that `if`, and increment it every time.